# How this CRC (Cyclic Redundancy Check) calculation can be solved?

Tags: hex, checksum, crc, crc16

I want to send data to a TCP 105 circuit.

The following hex command is OK to send data 123:

7F30001103 313233 **45D4**

Here, 313233 is hex representation of 123 and 45D4 is the CRC value.

I'm in problem to obtain this 45D4 after calculating CRC. After searching for a long time on the web, I'm getting other CRC values in different standards. But those CRC values are not being accepted by my LED display circuit.

Please help me to know how is it possible to get 45D4 from 7F30001103313233.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get `0x9A8F` with my method on the 8 bytes. Are you supposed to compute CRC on the 8 bytes or only a subsdet? CRC depends on the polynom you're using even if the same algorithm is used. CRC reversal, that's a tricky one!!

Comment: I've tested with 0x9A8F also but no success.  May be its CRC-16. CRC reversal will be D445 instead of 45D4.

Answer (score 0):

The command matches an algorithm called CRC-16/CMS.

```
$ reveng -w 16 -s 7f30001103313233d445
width=16  poly=0x8005  init=0xffff  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  ch
eck=0xaee7  name="CRC-16/CMS"
```

This is *probably* the correct algorithm, as you've only given one codeword (and because I've assumed that the CRC has been byte-swapped.)

To generate code that computes this CRC, see Mark Adler's [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) tool, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for such wonderful reply Regregex. I hope this will work and I gonna try it.